# Need help getting application.html.erb file to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails and starting a new project. I've created the basic rails app and am trying to build the front end of the application with bootstrap. I started out by making a simple "Hello World" Home page and about page and set up my routs.rb file.

When I tried to add links in my application.html.erb file they aren't rendering on either page. Here's what I've got so far. I'm just trying to create a basic nav-bar but the links aren't showing up.

Any suggestions?

routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'pages#home'
get "about" => "pages#about" #creates about path
```

Pages controller

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  #Define a generic method
  def home
  end 

  def about
  end
end
```

application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>CodeaApp</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
   <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
    <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controllers should inherit from `ApplicationController`, eg:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
```

When your controller inherits from ApplicationController it will use your `application.html.erb` file and insert the content from your view file via `yield`.